# swift firebase keep user signed in

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for my user authentication. I want to keep the user signed in when exiting the app if they have not logged out which I am able to do. But I can only do that in of the view controller with the following code shown. Problem is that for a few sec I see the previous view controller before the profile controller shows up. I think maybe the problem can be solved if I can write the code in the App delegate but I had no luck implementing it in the app delegate.

Can someone help me to get this figured out? Basically only my profile page shows up when I load the app again.

```
enter code here


let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "usersignedin")
```

override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

```
    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (result, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: "usersignedin")
            self.userDefault.synchronize()
            print(result?.user.email)
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more what is your actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue before and I have the exact solution for this.

Add these two variables to the top of your AppDelegate:

```
let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: “usersignedin”)
```

Those allow you to use userDefaults and then allows you to set a key called 'launchedBefore'.

Within your Firebase Login Function add this:

```
//You should have the next line for whatever method you're using to authenticate your users using firebase

    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: "usersignedin")
                self.userDefault.synchronize()
                print(result?.user.email)
```

If there is no error with login set 'usersignedin' bool to true.

In your login View Controller add this to viewDidAppear:

```
            if userDefault.bool(forKey: "usersignedin") {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Verified", sender: self)
        }
```

If the user is logged in to the app perform segue to the protected page.

Comment: I tried implementing your method. But no matter what I did, when I define those variables in app delegate I get an error in the view controller for not recognizing those variables.

Comment: Oh you need to also add it to the view controller, this should solve the problem. Let me know

Comment: can you help me define credential in my code? I am sure I should use values from Auth.auth() for the credential. but I don't know how to set it up right

Comment: import FirebaseAuth. Notice I changed the key for the second variable at the top of AppDelegate, please change accordingly. Try all of this and let me know

Comment: it is still giving me an error for defining credential

Comment: Upload your view controller and AppDelegate, to this question, will add to it and give you updated code

Comment: I added what I am putting in my view controller. I am importing Auth too. I am defining those two first variables in app delegate too. I am getting this error: Use of unresolved identifier 'credential'

Comment: Can you edit your question with the AppDelegate and ViewController

Comment: Your original question has been answered, please mark as answer @Sara. What you are asking to do will take you an unnecessary amount of time to implement. This is because you would  need to initiate your sign in method from the appDelegate, and set up rootViewController methods to switch to profile page. What would make this harder is if you have more than one sign in method. If you really hate that one second delay, open the question as a new question, and me and other would be happy to help. Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: no Problem I marked as answered. Is there anyway you can send me a code in the email that works with your method? titoosara@icloud.com because I still have no idea how to get the credential work